# How to create new kayboard layout in xorg?

Tags: fedora, xorg, xkb, bspwm, setxkbmap

I use polish layout, but when I use <kbd>AltGr</kbd>(in my case it is <kbd>right Alt</kbd>)+<kbd>b</kbd> in terminal it is print `”` and same situation with <kbd>AltGrgr</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> -- `æ`.

I use:

- Fedora workstation 37
- Xorg
- Bspwm
- Thinkpad A485

I tried to create new layout without `æ` and `”` mapping.

```
    $ sudo cp /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pl /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/custom_pl
    $ sudo nvim /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/custom_pl
    -- Before --
        key <AC04>  { [         f,          F,           ae,           AE ] };
    ...
        key <AB05>  { [         b,          B, rightdoublequotemark, leftdoublequotemark ] };
    -- Before --

    -- After --
            key <AC04>  { [         f,          F,           ,            ] };
        ...
            key <AB05>  { [         b,          B, ,  ] };
    -- After --
```

Add `custom_pl` to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xorg.lst`:

```
...
  no              Norwegian
  pl              Polish
  custom_pl       Polish (Good to bash shortcuts)
  pt              Portuguese
  ro              Romanian
...
```

and `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xorg.xml`:

```
    <layout>
      <configItem>
        <name>custom_pl</name>
        <!-- Keyboard indicator for Polish with normal linux shourtcut layouts -->
        <shortDescription>custom_pl</shortDescription>
        <description>Polish</description>
        <countryList>
          <iso3166Id>PL</iso3166Id>
        </countryList>
        <languageList>
          <iso639Id>pol</iso639Id>
        </languageList>
      </configItem>
      <variantList>
        <variant>
          <configItem>
            <name>legacy</name>
            <description>Polish (legacy)</description>
          </configItem>
        </variant>
      </variantList>
    </layout>
```

Add new layout to `xorg.conf.d`

```
 $ sudo nvim /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf
```

```
# Written by systemd-localed(8), read by systemd-localed and Xorg. It's
# probably wise not to edit this file manually. Use localectl(1) to
# instruct systemd-localed to update it.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "system-keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        Option "XkbLayout" "custom_pl, ua"
        Option "XkbModel" "pc105+inet"
        Option "XkbOptions" "grp:alt_shift_toggle"
EndSection
```

Reboot pc. And I have an error:

```
$ localectl set-keymap custom_pl                                                                       
    Failed to set keymap: Keymap custom_pl is not installed.
```

```
$ setxkbmap custom_pl
Error loading new keyboard description
```

I tried:
https://michal.kosmulski.org/computing/articles/custom-keyboard-layouts-xkb.html
https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/how-to-define-custom-keyboard-mappings-under-fedora-silverblue/77368

Nothing, I still don't have custom_pl layout. Can you help me with it?